# Exporting Threejs Scene to Obj Format

Tags: three.js

It seems that Three.js allows loading geometry from OBJ files (Blender, 3DsMax, etc), but is there any support for exporting a Three.js scene into an OBJ file (or any other formats)?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

By looking extensively at the GitHub repository, I found [an OBJ exporter](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/3510fdd91725f7681db845efd889c5e29e6e7446/examples/js/exporters/OBJExporter.js) (not shipped with three.js):

```js
var exporter = new THREE.OBJExporter();
exporter.parse(mesh);
```

Comment: how would you export it with a .mtl texture file? :(

Comment: It should be `exporter.parse(mesh);` not `exporter.parse(geometry);`

Comment: THREE.Object3D could be passed to `parse` as of this writing.