# export from Three.js to .obj

Tags: three.js, export

I've seen a lot of explanations for how to import .obj files into Three.js, but I was wondering if there was a way to do the opposite? I have a Three.js program that can randomly generate shapes, and I want to export them as .obj files. Is there a way to do this?

Or, if not, is there another programming format that I should recreate my code with that does have this ability? Thank you.

Comment: [Exporting Threejs Scene to Obj Format](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19351419/6521116)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exporting Threejs Scene to Obj Format](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19351419/6521116)

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to use the [OBJExporter](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/exporters/OBJExporter.js).